# How do I activate an end portal?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

The 0.9.5 update is out with a new block called the End Portal. But, I still can't figure out how to activate it and go to The End. Some videos in YouTube told me that I need ender eye, but I can't find it in the creative inventory.

Comment: "Eye of Ender" is the actual item name. As for "activating the End portal", are you generating one, or have you found one in a fortress? Because (if I remember correctly) only the naturally generated portals can be activated, by placing an Eye of Ender in each block.

Answer (score 4):

*The Answer bellow relates to versions before Alpha 0.12.1, before the Nether was introduced. the Question asks about Alpha 0.9.5*

Going by the [Version History](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history#0.9.0) the End Portal Block was added in 0.9.0 and according to the [history](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Portal_%28block%29#History) for the block they can not be used to access [The End](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End), probably because (to my knowledge) even in the current version of 0.10.4 (at the time of writing) for Pocket Edition...

- The [Eye of Ender](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Eye_of_Ender#History) hasn't been added and neither has it's parent items, the [Ender Pearl](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Pearl#History) and [Blaze Powder](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Blaze_Powder) (because there is still no [Nether](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether) and the [Nether Reactor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Reactor) does not spawn Blaze Powder).
- The End itself does not exists in Pocket Edition

In the PC Edition. the End Portal Block (or Frame) is naturally generated inside [Strongholds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold) in the formation they need to be in order to be able to open a portal to The End (5x5 Square Ring)

Comment: Add this please: "The end hasn't been added in the PE version"

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 i would assume the lack of an entry in the wiki's history of it being added would be a clear enough sign but it probably was a better idea to spell that out in the answer

Comment: :) that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

To get endereye, you have to get a blazerod and an enderpearl :) But the end isn't in PE and same with the endereye.

Edit: The end is added as of december 19'th. So just put endereyes in all the empty frames

Comment: Actually, as of December 19, Pocket Edition now has the end.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the post

Answer (score 0):

You can make an end portal in survival cheats or creative!

Items needed: 9 random blocks (Don't use the blocks that the portal is on), 9 end portal parts, 12 eyes of ender (Blaze powder + ender pearl)

Step 1: Make a 3 by 3 hole in the ground (1 block deep)

Step 2: Fill it in with random blocks (Not the blocks that the portal is on)

Step 3: Stand at the middle of the 3 by 3 blocks and start puting down the end portal peices (Please stand at the middle and don't move)

Step 4: Fill the end portal with eyes of ender

DONE, you're ready to go!